# Why OnDisappearing() method is invoke when gallery is open using Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, gallery

I am creating a camera app using Xam.Plugin.Media, when I open the gallery or the phone camera the page OnDisappearing() function invoked and the app dissappear.I have added all the permissions and code with in the reference link and the same code is working in a sample project, I don't know why this happens only in this project.

This is the link I used:-https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Please help me

Comment: I think that is how OnDisappearing is supposed to work

Comment: I would assume the OS is reclaiming memory.

Comment: Is there any solution to this?